# Sources discussing Trick Candles

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work, fire-burning

Are there any rabbinic sources which discuss whether one can blow out a "[trick candle](https://science.howstuffworks.com/innovation/science-questions/question420.htm)" on Shabbat?

I see issues related to [m'chabeh](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/the-39-melachos/melacha37/) but also possibly [mavir](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/the-39-melachos/melacha36/), but because the intent is not to relight, the destructive nature of the former might not be present (though there might be a psik reishe for the latter because the destruction is temporary).

Comment: It seems in this case the flame is not completely extinguished, but it is certainly diminished which is already problematic with respect to michabeh.

Comment: The wick turns into charcoal; how could this possibly be permitted?